# Migrar datos de base de datos a otra base de datos

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos base de datos iguales, pero una tiene información que deberia estar en la otra, al desconocer cuantos son los datos que son, me vengo a la necesidad si existe alguna herramienta externa o del mismo SQL para poder pasar sola la infomacion inexistente en una base de datos a otra que son totalmente igual. Saludos

Comment: has evaluado replicar en mysql? [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html]

Comment: Perderia la información de las base de datos ?, la prioridad es no perder nada de información.

Comment: Creo que ya estoy entendiendo tu comentario, solo necesito algo parecido como la insercion masiva en .CSV, despues de esto la segunda base de datos queda obsoleta